# grouping amount by date and person id

Tags: sql, date, group-by, sql-server-2012, where-clause

I need a way to only show the salary amount that correlates with the highest date for each emp_num(person).

```
select

lge.emp_num,
lge.emp_lname,
lge.emp_fname,
lgs.sal_from,
lgs.sal_amount

from lgemployee lge
join lgsalary_history lgs
on lge.emp_num = lgs.emp_num
where lge.dept_num in ('300')
group by lge.emp_num, lge.emp_lname, lge.emp_fname, lgs.sal_from, lgs.sal_amount
order by lgs.sal_amount desc
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture several people show up more then once where they have multiple dates of pay. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope you're not publishing people's real names and salaries online here.

Comment: @WoutervanNifterick, who would work for only 95Ks these days? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```
select
    lge.emp_num, lge.emp_lname, lge.emp_fname,
    lgs1.sal_from, lgs1.sal_amount
from (
    select emp_num, max(sal_from) maxDate from lgsalary_history
    group by emp_num
) lgs2
join lgsalary_history lgs1
on lgs1.emp_num = lgs2.emp_num and lgs1.sal_from = lgs2.maxDate
join lgemployee lge
on lgs1.emp_num = lge.emp_num
where lge.dept_num in ('300')
order by lgs1.sal_amount desc
```

Comment: I think this is on track for what I want, but I'm a little confused by how to implement it into my existing code.

Comment: Oh, there were 2 tables! Sorry I didnt see lge and lgs, let me rething this